# How to open a specific Fragment when clicking on a home screen widget

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

How to open a specific Fragment when clicking on a home screen widget, I can already open an Activity but I have no idea about how to open a fragment from a widget this is my widget class

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
ComponentName watchWidget;
RemoteViews remoteViews;
private static final String SYNC_CLICKED = "automaticWidgetSyncButtonClick";

void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int appWidgetId) {



    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.My_widgets);
    watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text,"Widget Example");
    // start Activity from the widget

    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, configPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

So any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not pass some flag (Bundle) to Intent and check it in Activity onCreate or onNewIntent and if set to true (or any value) open Fragment?

Widget:

```
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
configIntent.putExtra("key", value);
configIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
```

Activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    value_type value = extras.get("key");        
}
```

Remember that you have to check it both in onCreate and onNewIntent.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For the Navigation component use deep links

Manifest: Add this line to your activity section in the android manifest

```
<activity>
    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/main_nav_graph" />
</activity>
```

Navigation graph:

```
<fragment
...>
 <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="myapp://example.com/text" />
</fragment>
```

ExWidget.kt: Declare your pending intent in your widget file.

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
                .setGraph(R.navigation.main_nav_graph)
                .setDestination(R.id.your_fragment)
                .setArguments(
                    YourFragmentArgs.Builder(arguments
                    ).build().toBundle())
                .createPendingIntent()
```

and assign this pendingIntent in the setOnClickPendingIntent method,

```
val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.example_widget)   
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.example_widget_button, pendingIntent)
```